# Algorithm in c++ with bitwise operators

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation, boolean-expression

My professor assigned this task for the next week. You have to create variables and within one expression make an algorithm that gives 1 (true) when the given x, y, z are calculated and in each other state of x, y, z the result is 0. Using only bitwise operators(|, &).

```
x = 1
y = 0
z = 0
result 1

x = 0
y = 1
z = 0
result 1

x = 0
y = 1
z = 1
result 1
```

Everything else should be 0 (false)! We should not use any functions, loops, switches or anything else. Just 1 line of expression.
He said we should use 9 variables and 8 operations so my guess is that the algorithm should look like this:

```
(xOyOz) O (xOyOz) O (xOyOz)
```

This gives 9 variables `3*x`, `3*y`, `3*z` and 8 operations `8*O` (one of the following should be in this place |, &)

Comment: You need to use a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: This should be a tough task. To begin with, how should be distinguish `x=3` from `x=1`?

Comment: @ergonaut Note that NOT operation cannot be used here.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you be more specific about the requirements? When does your algorithm return true and when should it return false?
Can you also make an example where the expected return value is false?

Comment: @MikeCAT then there must be something wrong with the question.  Can you check with the question/prof to make sure you have all the pieces here?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: A little clarification for those who got confused: Imagine that you have to write an algorith which always returns 0 ( false ) as a result but only in three given situations it gives 1 ( true ) as a result. The situations are the following:

       x = 1, y = 0, z = 0      result = 1;
       x = 0, y = 1, z = 0      result = 1;
       x = 0, y = 1, z = 1      result = 1;

the code should be something like this: ((x|y) & z) | (x & (y|z)) & (x | (y & z)) but this is not the correct code it should be something similar returning 0(false) in all cases but in the three mentioned states.

Comment: Ick, I hate how it displays my name after the most *common* close reason even though I marked it as "too broad" ...

Comment: A simple solution would be ((x & z) | y) ^ x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ^ (XOR) operator.

```
((x^y)&(x^z))|(y&(x^y)&(y^z))
```

Thats exacly 9 variables and 8 operations

Comment: Mine solution is probably what your prof asked you for.

Comment: doubt it, it's in the wrong form (not (xOyOz) O (xOyOz) O (xOyOz)), uses XOR when only AND/OR are allowed and doesn't give a general algorithm where as mine does

Comment: In question there was no word about this kind of format. I assumed that defnotme forgot about ^ bitwise operator, while it is valid bitwise operator. Your is using ~ that was told not to use it.

Comment: so it's either ^ was forgotten about and the question was a beastly conundrum or ~ was something allowed on variables and not counted as an operation and the prof was after Karnaugh Maps which are taught universally

Comment: sure. Question is not precise enought. Using xor is equally easy.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is that for each 1 result:

1. You `&` together all the bit variables as 1s (`not` any the 0s to make them 1s with `~`).
2. Then `|` these groups together.
3. Optionally refactor this general solution to a simpler form.

This will give you not only a 1 result for all the given 1 results but a 0 result for every other combination.

Therefore the (un-optimized) bit wise expression in this case is:

```
(x & ~y & ~z) | (~x & y & ~z) | (~x & y & z)
```

This is know as a [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) and is not only widely used in bit manipulation but also as a general purpose boolean filter for data of any kind.

Comment: thanks for your help ! Much appreciated !

Comment: Again, you did not specify the not operator was a valid operator.  Your question remains invalid.